# Retrieving a display results from a search

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, iron-router

I'm relatively new to meteor.js and I'm trying to get a search form to work. So far I'm not even trying to get the params to work, but it will come later.

I'm basically trying to get a bunch of lifts to display.

**lib/router.js**

```
Router.configure({
  layoutTemplate: 'layout',
  loadingTemplate: 'loading',
  notFoundTemplate: 'notFound',
  waitOn: function() {
    return Meteor.subscribe('lifts');
  }
});

Router.route('/', { name: 'liftsList' });

Router.route('/lifts/search/:from-:to-:when', {
  name: 'liftsSearch',
  waitOn: function() {
    return Meteor.subscribe('liftsSearch');
  }
});
```

**server/publications.js**

```
Meteor.publish('liftsSearch', function() {
  var query = { fromLoc: { $near : { 
    $geometry: { 
      type : "Point" ,
      coordinates: [ 6.11667, 45.9 ]
    } },
    $maxDistance : 50
  }};

  return Lifts.find(query);
});
```

If I try to display the results with Lifts.find(query).fetch(), it returns actual results.

**client/lifts_search.html**

```
<template name="liftsSearch">
  <div class="container">
    <h3>Lifts search results {{hi}}</h3>
    <div class="lifts">
      {{#each lifts}}
        hi
        {{> liftItem}}
      {{/each}}
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Here I simply got no lifts displaying, not even the little "hi" string.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless there's code that you haven't included, `{{#each lifts}}` isn't rendering because you're not defining `lifts` anywhere.  Just because you're populating the `Lifts` collection, the template doesn't automatically known that `lifts` refers to it (largely because that would be totally arbitrary - what exact query would it refer to?).

So, you need to define `lifts` in either a router [`data` function](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md#rendering-templates-with-data):

```
Router.route('/lifts/search/:from-:to-:when', {
  name: 'liftsSearch',
  waitOn: function() {
    return Meteor.subscribe('liftsSearch');
  },
  data: function() {
    return {
      lifts: Lifts.find() // add a query if you want
    }
  }
});
```

Or in a [template helper](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_helpers):

```
Template.liftsSearch.helpers({
  lifts: function() {
    return Lifts.find(); // add a query if you want
  }
});
```

Comment: So in the router what is the exact relation between Meteor.subscribe('liftsSearch') & Lifts.find()? Is the subscribe function returning a minimongo instance, and then the Lift.find() querying within this minimongo instance?

Comment: The `subscribe` function asks the server to send docs pertaining to that publication name, which the `publish` function does, using `Lifts.find(query)` to determine which that is.  However, just because these have now populated the minimongo, doesn't automatically make them available to a template.  To do so, you have to query on the client side and return the results in a helper/router data function.  If it wasn't like that, you'd have to subscribe for every individual client query, which would be punishing for the server.

Comment: I understand, but the issue is that if I do a fetch() on the server side (publish), I see that I have only two elements, whether on the client side the Lift.find() is simply retrieving all the elements.

Comment: Have you removed `autopublish`?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, this is actually two problems?  1 - the client `find` returns more than you're publishing. 2 - the template doesn't render the list of lifts.  Correct?

Comment: Yes I did. I edited my question to show more of the code of the router. The issue seems to be that I have two subscribe, one for liftsList and one for liftsSearch therefore creating a conflict. In this case, using the subscribe is probably not the right for performing a search query.

Comment: No, it's not.  You already have the data, you just need to run the appropriate query on the client to deliver it to the template.

Comment: Yes, but I can't run mongo spatial queries (or whatever that is called) running on the client side. So this search query still needs to be done on the server side.

Comment: Understood.  In that case you need a [Meteor method](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_methods) to return the id's of the relevant pitches, so you can do the search on the server and then find and fetch those ids on the client.